# Xubuntu 16.04 freezing regularly

Tags: xubuntu, swap

Today I began experiencing regular freezes on Xubuntu, within 5 minutes of booting up or so. No particular program seems to trigger the freeze, and I don't recall any modifications of my system recently before the problem began.

One strange thing I noticed was the output of "free -h". The swap line had all zeros under used, free, and share. I then went to Gparted and noticed a yellow warning sign for the swap partition (see photo 1). I clicked on the yellow warning sign and got more detail (see photo 2). I then used Gparted to reformat that partition. I used the format linux-swap. Then I tried free -h again but the swap line still had all zeros. Is there something else I needed to do in order for Xubuntu to recognize the swap partition? Could this swap partition even be related to the freezing problem?

I should also mention that the SysRq key does not seem to be working on my keyboard. Looking at other forum posts related to this problem led me to try alt+sysrq+f and alt+sysrq+reisub but nothing happens. Anorther thing I notice is that every time the system freezes the Caps lock light starts flashing!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
[image: Photo 1]

[image: Photo 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CAPS lock light flashing means that you didn't have a freeze, you had a hard kernel crash.

Best to solve the swap partition this way...

- in `terminal` do a `sudo swapoff -a` to disable all swaps
- in `terminal` do `sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bak`
- use `gparted` to delete /dev/sda6 and recreate it as linux-swap
- in `terminal` do a `sudo mkswap /dev/sda6` (assuming that the new swap partition is still sda6)
- note the new UUID
- copy the new UUID to the clipboard
- in `terminal` do `gksudo gedit /etc/fstab`
- find the line that has "swap" in it

  - ie: `UUID=071f8b0e-8e16-4f4d-90ff-a4ae9cc56e2b   none   swap   sw    0   0`
- replace the existing UUID with the new UUID with a paste
- save the file and quit gedit
- in `terminal` do `sudo swapon -a`
- in `terminal` do `free -h` and `swapon -s`
- confirm that swap is showing correctly now

**Update #1:**

- check to see if this file exists...

  `ls -al /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`
- if it does, update it with the UUID of the swap partition you obtained earlier...

  `gksudo gedit /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`

  `sudo update-initramfs -u`

Comment: free -h still returns zeros and swapon -s still returns nothing. I noticed when editing fstab that the line where I entered the new UUID began with '#'. Does this mean that line is commented out? Should I remove the # sign?

Comment: You're correct. The swap line is commented out, probably because of the problem with the swap partition. Remove the # and then try the last 3 commands from my answer. Does gparted now show a correct swap partition? Report back.

Comment: @user87317 ps: also do my update #1

Comment: Awesome. Yes, removing the '#' does it and Gparted does show a correct swap partition. It turned out that the file from update #1 didn't exist. Thanks for your help, @heynnema !

Comment: @user87317 Great news! Does the `free -h` and `swapon -s` now show correctly?

Comment: Yes it does. That was of course a couple of weeks ago (sorry about the late reply, didn't see your last question). However the problem came back again today. I revisited this thread to follow the steps and it solved the problem again.